# Storing input into file

Tags: java, regex

I am having an issue trying to search a text file for the exact input that a user enters. I want to output the sentence not only by direct user input but i want the program to recognize some word(s) that would signal the desired text. I got searching for the keyword part down pack and working but i am only able to search the text based on the keyword. I want to search based on the keyword and the entire inputted sentence. For example if the keyword is *e-mail* and the user enter's what is mars e-mail? and the text file contains "mars e-mail is mars3433@aol.com, john e-mail is anonymous"  i want to output mars e-mail is ... instead of both sentences. I am completely stuck trying to figure out this issue, Can anyone help me?

```
   public static class DicEntry {
    String key;
    String[] syns;
    Pattern pattern;

    public DicEntry(String key, String... syns) {
        this.key = key;
        this.syns = syns;
        pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(?:"
                + Stream.concat(Stream.of(key), Stream.of(syns))
                        .map(x -> "\\b" + Pattern.quote(x) + "\\b")
                        .collect(Collectors.joining("|")) + ").*");
    }
}

public static void removedata(String s) throws IOException {

    File f = new File("data.txt");
    File f1 = new File("data2.txt");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(f1);
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains(s)) {

            System.out.println("Enter new Text :");
            String newText = input.readLine();
            line = newText;
            System.out.println("Thank you, Have a good Day!");

        }

        pr.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
    pr.close();
    input.close();
    Files.move(f1.toPath(), f.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

}

public static void parseFile(String s) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner forget = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int flag_found = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {

            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile);
            flag_found = 1;

            System.out
                    .println(" Would you like to update this information ? ");
            String yellow = forget.nextLine();
            if (yellow.equals("yes")) {
                removedata(lineFromFile);
            } else if (yellow.equals("no")) {

                System.out.println("Have a good day");
                // break;
            }

        }

    }
    if (flag_found == 0) {// input is not found in the txt file so
                            // flag_found remains 0
        writer();
    }

}

public static void writer() {
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    File file = new File("data.txt");
    try (BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
            file.getAbsoluteFile(), true))) { // Creates a writer object
                                                // called wr
                                                // file.getabsolutefile
                                                // takes the filename and
                                                // keeps on storing the old
        System.out.println("I Do not know, Perhaps you want to teach me?"
                + "..."); // data
        while ((Keyboard.hasNext())) {

            String lines = Keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print(" is this correct ? ");
            String go = input.nextLine();

            if (go.equals("no")) {
                System.out.println("enter line again");
                lines = Keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.print(" is this correct ? ");
                go = input.nextLine();
            }

            else if (go.equals("yes")) {
                wr.write(lines);
                // wr.write("\n");

                wr.newLine();

                wr.close();
            }

            System.out.println("Thankk you");
            break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" cannot write to file " + file.toString());
    }
}

private static List<DicEntry> populateSynonymMap() {
    List<DicEntry> responses = new ArrayList<>();
    responses.add(new DicEntry("student", "pupil", "scholar"));
    responses.add(new DicEntry("office", "post", "room"));
    responses.add(new DicEntry("topics", "semester talk"));

    return responses;
}

public static void getinput() throws IOException {

    List<DicEntry> synonymMap = populateSynonymMap(); // populate the map

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    /* End Initialization */
    System.out.println("Welcome ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String[] inputs = input.split(" ");

    int flag_found = 0;

    for (DicEntry entry : synonymMap) { // iterate over each word of the
                                        // sentence.

        if (entry.pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
            // System.out.println(entry.key);
            parseFile(entry.key);
            flag_found = 1;// Input is found

        }

    }
    if (flag_found == 0) {// input is not found in the txt file so
                            // flag_found remains 0
        writer();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
    /* Initialization */
    getinput();

}

  }
```

So my methods work like this, the parse file method searching the text file for the keyword in the sentence. My writer( ) writes to the file if the input is not found and my remove data ( ) erases the line and updates it with the new string upon user request. and get input is just a method to get information from the scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, additional obstacle is fact, that some word can repeat in unrelated sentences. My solution seems to be quite long for me, but it works. However when I test it, I didn't use your dicEntry. It is impossible to hard-code all synonyms, so you should reconsider this approach.
I added one class, jast as data holder for int repetition variable (see below) and  particular sentence:

```
public class Pair {
    int repetitions;
    String sentence;

    public Pair(int rep, String string){
        repetitions = rep;
        sentence = string;
    }

    public int getRepetitions() {
        return repetitions;
    }

    public String getSentence() {
        return sentence;
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a method, which loop through input sentence, and file content, looking for sentence from file, in which most inputs words repeted. I pretty sure, it is not most efficient way, but I don't know another :P.

```
public static String getMostAppropriate(String[] input) throws IOException{
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    ArrayList<Pair> pairs  = new ArrayList<>();
    int repetitions = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String newLine = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] line = newLine.split(","); // this regex depends on your file format style,
        String oneSentence = "";
        for(String sentence : line){  // for sentence in file lines
            for(String string : sentence.split(" ")){  // for words in these sentences
                for(String word : input){  // for words from input
                    if(word.equals(string)){
                        repetitions += 1;
                        oneSentence = sentence;
                    }
                }
            }
            pairs.add(new Pair(repetitions,oneSentence));
            repetitions = 0;
        }
    }
    return mostCommon(pairs);
}
```

The argument is `String[] inputs` form your `getInput` method. In return statement I called another new method, which looks for sentences with most repetitions:

```
public static String mostCommon(ArrayList<Pair> pairs){
    Pair max = new Pair(0,"");
    String result = "";
    for(Pair pair : pairs){
        if(pair.getRepetitions() > max.getRepetitions()){
            result = pair.getSentence();
            max = pair;
        }else if(pair.getRepetitions()==max.getRepetitions()){
            result += "; " + pair.getSentence();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If some sentences have same number of repetitions, it returns both(or more) connected into one sentence (sentence; sentence; etc.).

Implementation into your code I left for you, if you are interested.

As I said, I didn't use your dicEntry, still you can add it as additional loop, but chacking whole dictionary will not be too effective with my method.

Also, if I were you, I would divide some of your methods into smaller one, I mean like: read file in one, ask for additional input in another. Because it is easier to implement changes this way. You don't need to keep eye on whole method, just arguments they pass to each other.

I hope you will find something useful in my post.

Comment: I am getting some errors in your code.  *pairs.add(new Pair(repetitions,oneSentence));* the error is                                                      *No enclosing instance of type check is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type check (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of check).*

Comment: @LexMars Did you put Pair class in different file than rest on code or as inner class? You can also change it to static, it should work then.

Comment: @LexMars here is how I was testing your code [link](http://hastebin.com/vawekikoco.avrasm)